# Функция что заменяет символы в строке, но по отдельности, а не ReplaceAll

Tags: java

Нужно создать функцию которая будет заменять каждый сивол по отдельности.
Например
String str = "abc";
functionName(str где "a" замени на "b", "b" замени на "c" );
В конечном итоги результат должен быть "bcc". Ступор происходит на том моменте, что заменив первый "a" на "b", он потом меняется на "с"
и результат получается "ccc". А нужно что бы он после первой замены дальше не шёл.
Но пользователь сам будет выбирать, что он будет менять. Если скажем надо будет заменить в имени "Маша",
первое "a" на "и", а второе "а" на "е". То есть поменял два одинаковых символа на разные.

Comment: o_O ReplaceFirst()

Comment: Она замеяет только первый символ, а мне нужно заменять один и тот же символ на разные, в зависимости от позиции.

Comment: А вызывать его в цикле?

Comment: Можно пример? Я делитант в этом деле, не сразу могу всё представить.

Comment: ?? Походу нужен маппинг с одного алфавита на другой.

Comment: Не. Работа с одним алфавитом. Просто заменять нужно по отедельности. 
Если скажем слово "Дарама", где нужно заменить каждый "а" на отдельную букву, то функция это должна уметь. Вот пример тестирования Assert.assertEquals(expected:"bb cc cc", Arrays.asList(То что имеем"aa bb cc ", какие символы на какие нужно заменить  "aa" , "bb", "bb", "cc"));

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```
public class ReplaceLetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "Привет с Большого Бодуна!"; // исходная строка
        String[] replacemet = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}; // на что меняем
        System.out.println(replace(source, "о", replacemet)); // о - что меняем

    }
    public static String replace(String source, String  replaceable, String[] replacemet) {
        for(int x = 0; x < replacemet.length; x++) {
            source = source.replaceFirst(replaceable, replacemet[x]);
        }
        return source;
    }

}
```

На выходе получим `Привет с Б1льш2г3 Б4дуна!`. Все буквы "о" заменены на разные значения.

Comment: Спасибо. А как сделать на него тест?

Comment: Тест надо делать не например, а на тот код, который вы используете в своём приложении. Как конкретно его делать зависит от фреймворка (JUnit, TestNG и пр.) который вы используете, смотрите документацию.